# Middle click pasting does not working in native apps

Tags: release-juno

I just installed elementary OS 5 Juno and realized that middle click pasting of marked text does not work in native apps anymore. In other apps, however, it works!

I've tested the following applications.

Works in:

- Firefox
- Thunderbird
- Spotify
- LibreOffice Writer

Doesn't work in:

- Code
- Terminal
- Music
- Photos
- AppCenter
- App menu (is it called slingshot?)

All tests were done with mouse and trackpad. Middle click in mouse settings was enabled.

Does anyone know how to fix this or where I could file a bug report, since this seems to affect multiple apps?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same situation as @Heiko.

Casually, I installed elementary-tweaks and disabled "Natural copy paste" in the Terminal subsection and now I can copy&paste with middle click from any app to the Terminal.

This would be a workarround.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Neither for me, no joy, searching the web for hours, no solution. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out why it kept failing: somehow the gtk-enabe-primary-paste option was disabled.  Re-enabling it finally solved it.

`org.gnome.desktop.interface.gtk-enable-primary-paste`

The other one to check is the natural copy paste option

`io.elementary.terminal.settings.natural-copy-paste`